# Run a call every few sec using php

Tags: php, combinations, wait, sleep

I have around 900 combinations which need to check through an external party for validation.I need to perform below-mentioned steps :

Step 1 : Insert all 900 combinations in table **[DONE]**

**Now I need to do this**

Step 2: Run a call every few secs (add PHP wait function)

Step 3: store the result in the DB

so that if something fails, we can start it again from where it failed

Tried php code :

```
 $t0  = microtime(true);
                        $i   = 0;
                        do{     
                            $dt = round(microtime(true)-$t0);
                            if($dt!= $i){
                                $i = $dt;
                                if(($i % 2) == 0) //every 2 seconds
                              
                                echo $i.PHP_EOL;     
                            }   
                        }
                        while($dt<10); //max execution time
```

> Cannot use setInterval in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `sleep(2)`. In case you want more granular you can use [time_nanosleep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time-nanosleep.php)

Please also find an example how to make chunks in php.

```
$arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
$chunked = array_chunk($arr, 5);
$res = [];
$flag = 0;
foreach($chunked as $arr){ 
    sleep(2);
    echo 'sleep';
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        var_dump($val);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have 15 records I want to execute them in set of 3[5 record in each set],I want first set should execute without sleep and then 2 set should use sleep then?

Comment: Add a variable inside loop to increment, and if variable is > 0 - sleep.

Comment: But how to create bunch of 5 records each time?

Comment: I would split an array with array_chunk and then make a foreach inside foreach :)

Comment: Could you please guide me ,below is what I am using ===>foreach($db_array as $arr){
                
                if($flag>4) { 

                    sleep(2);
                 }
                
                if($flag >= 15 ) break;

                $flag++;
                    
                   $res[] = $arr;}

Comment: I'll update in the evening, although this comment qualifies for separate question ;)

Comment: @Komss updated the answer, please accept if you find it useful. Thank you.

Comment: maybe vote it useful at least :) Or is it bad answer?